# Keeping all columns in a single table vs keeping in separate table by category of data

Tags: mysql

I've a mysql table "login" with columns **name, userid, pass, email**. and another table "info" with columns **bio, skills, searchingfor, badge, likes, age**

here, the 1st table is used to check login... and the rest is used for storing personal info of an user. but  i have a search box where people can search user according to everything except bio & pass. I'm having problem joining the results from two tables so is it ok to put all in one table or is there a simplier way?

and if i put everything in a table would it be heavier for mysql queries to search if the database gets lots of data?

Comment: Why are you having problems joining the tables? If `skills` is a list of things, it shouldn't be a single column, it should be a table all its own, with one row for each skill that a person has.

Comment: the same goes for `likes`. Learn about database normalization, you should never have a list in a single column.

Comment: i wanted but the person who gave me the job, wants to keep skills in column as comma separeted value and search by FIND_IN_SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no higher load on your mysql server if you combine both tables. This is a valid idea, since it appears that you have a 1:1 relationship anyway, so the code get's easier. Actually the load will be *lower*, since you do not need a join which is actually very slow in relational database management systems. The performance (load) just depends on your indexes and filter requirements, but that is independent of whether you search in one or two tables.

On the other hand: there is no reason why you should not be able to join those tables as required. So maybe you want to solve your issue here first. And be it just to learn how to do do it ;-)

Comment: Thanks that gave me a big relief :)